# How to use magnific popup with ajax post and url?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi all is there a way to use magnific popup with ajax, I will be using it to insert data once magnific popup triggered.

here's my code:

```
$(function () {

    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insertVote.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,

    success: function(html) {
    parent.html(html);
     }  
}); 

    });
return false;
```

Comment: what is error you are facing? check error console.

Comment: dont see why not.  if you have reason to believe otherwise, please share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use callback function:

```
$('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({

  callbacks : {

    open : function(){
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insertVote.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
             parent.html(html);
          }  
       });
    }
  }
});
```